# Efficient join relation one to two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join one table to another.

T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 or T1.Col1 = T2.Col2

This approach is time expensive the query run over 40 min so I dropped it.
I changed it to `Coalese(T2.Col1,T2.Col2)` query it is fast but I lost data when both T2.Col1 and T2.Col2 can be related to T1.Col1 but in a different row.
Is there a better option? I do need to get a left join with T1 and only add data from T2.

Output

| T1.ID | T2.TRANS1 | T2.TRANS2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | null | null |

Expected output

| T1.ID | T2.TRANS1 | T2.TRANS2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 |

```
Select *
FROM  dbo.TestGeneralTransYear2022 AS ledger
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SRM_InventTransSettlementTab AS trans ON ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = COALESCE (trans.VOUCHER COLLATE Polish_CI_AS, trans.voucherphysical COLLATE Polish_CI_AS)
```

| SUBLEDGERVOUCHER | VOUCHERPHYSICAL | VOUCHER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FSI22000031 | WZ-0187127 | FSI22000031 |
| FSI22000031 | WZ-0187127 | FSI22000031 |
| FSI22000031 | WZ-0187127 | FSI22000031 |
| WZ-0187127 | NULL | NULL |
| WZ-0187127 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Please provide clear input examples for your output.

Comment: As a side note, that `COALESCE` *and* explicit `COLLATE` on your columns in the `ON` will be awful for performance; the query isn't SARGable.

Comment: consider splitting and union..

Comment: Maybe `T1.ID IN (t2.Trans1, t2.Trans2)` I wouldn't expect it to perform much different than the slow version, but sometimes the query optimizer will surprise you. The other option is two completely queries connected via a `UNION`.

Comment: Does the query have a `WHERE` predicate to filter out rows? If it doesn't, then you are retrieving the whole join. That's bound to be slow.

Comment: I did actually query the tables with WHERE before, I found out that using bigger views is not efficient and so The push to table and read is mostly faster than read from view. Both tables at this moment have around 30 mln rows.
So at this moment the tables have only the data I need nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues causing your performance woes with this query as written, and commenters accurately point to them.

First, the use of `COALESCE` and `COLLATE` in your `JOIN ON` predicate prevent the use of indexes to `SEEK` to the values. This causes the engine to perform multiple `SCAN`s of the tables, which can be very slow depending on row counts.

A (possibly) more performant approach is this (h/t to @P.Salmon for the "split and union" guidance):

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.TestGeneralTransYear2022     AS ledger
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SRM_InventTransSettlementTab AS trans
    ON ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = trans.VOUCHER
 WHERE trans.VOUCHER IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.TestGeneralTransYear2022     AS ledger
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SRM_InventTransSettlementTab AS trans
    ON ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = trans.voucherphysical
 WHERE trans.voucherphysical IS NOT NULL
```

This approach treats your `OR` conditions as discrete equalities, enabling a much more efficient search pattern.

Comment: Thanks. But sadly it still does not work as intended I still have records that should be matched but they doesn't and there are even more ot that type. And if I work with IS NOT NULL the end valeus don't match since I sum the trans values at the end so I removed it. I did also move the COLLATE into the table definition, the quesry is fast yet the valeus don't match.

Comment: @Tweene you could try making that a `UNION ALL` since it seems that duplicate row elimination is outside of your requirement scope

Comment: I think I see the problem. I need a second query to get the values of ledger that dont have a relation with this both trans columns

Comment: I managed to make it creating a second view with not exist and merging the data.